# How do I make a big url into a smaller url with appended parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url

Here is my problem.

I have a complex url - Example: www.mywebsite.com/first/second/something/index.html

And i want to convert it into something like www.mywebsite.com/index.html?a=64&e=453

I have seen this in some websites.

But I am not able to figure out how that is done. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to go for some framework like AngularJS or Backbone which has support for routing.

Comment: Use a db.. save as.. id=3 url=bldjfjdhdijdhdb(woteveryiucanputher) and call as out.php?bla=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would most likely depend on what web server you are using. If you are using Apache, you can do this with mod_rewrite. You can find a lot of documentation on exactly how to set this up online:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
https://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

For example, if you wanted to map a URL parameter to a path you could do something like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     a=64    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/index.html$       /first/second/something/index.html      [NC,L,R=301]
```

(I haven't tried that out, so the syntax might not be 100% correct.) But then you'd have to manually create a rule for every number to path mapping that you want, which might be a lot of work, so this might not be the best solution.

Comment: I am reading it and I think that is the technique. But its a super long read though. Is it possible that you can elaborate a bit more clearly? Then I will accept this answer.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but I can try to add some detail.

Comment: Thanks man. Its not exactly the same but you gave me the leads to solve my problem. I think people will benefit from the answer. I did not know that this mod_rewrite is like 15+ year old concept!

Answer (score 0):

Those URLs are generated by a server-side programming language, like PHP. The pages are generated dynamically, and are typically not desirable (because 'clean' URLs are easier to read and edit and better for SEO).

Technically, you can add `?a=64` to a regular web address and it won't prevent the page from rendering - but I'm not sure why anyone would want to do this.

Comment: My client name is Tobi as well :) He is an affiliate marketer and he just want shorter links. I know PHP, so how do i approach this problem?

Comment: You'll need to post some code for review - it's difficult to tell what would be the 'right' answer in this case.